# Replace js function is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
my arr = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

I want to replace single quotes from the array below is my logic. But still it's getting error.

```
JSON.parse(arr).toString().replace(/'/g,'')
```

Comment: Do you want output like aaabbbccc?

Comment: Seems [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can be used.

Comment: no like aaa,bbb,ccc

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you'd want to just join the array:

```
var arr = ['aaa','bbb','ccc'];
var output = arr.join(',');
```

Which gives `aaa,bbb,ccc`.

If for some reason you have an Array-like object that's not a real array (e.g. NodeList), call it instead:

```
var output = Array.prototype.join.call(arr, ',');
```

Comment: but my array is like means inside single qoutes 
  `arr = [" 'abb' " , " 'adf' "]`

Comment: @sarveshkumar Okay, we need to back up, here. What we have on our hands is an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking about Y (which is what you're doing), instead ask about X, which is your actual task you're working on. You're too far down a particular path, so I'd recommend you back up a bit and ask about the higher-level objective.